# Kinesis Producer Library - reading logs and sending to Amazon kinesis

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

I am new to Kinesis. I have tried and tested the java example here with BasicClickEventsToKinesis implementation: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3ET30EGDKUUI2/Implementing-Efficient-and-Reliable-Producers-with-the-Amazon-Kinesis-Producer-L

Now, in my application , I am reading a log file and I need  to send  every record in a file to the kinesis stream. I am able to create the click Event corresponding to each record and adding it to a "events" queue as per the test driver implementation

final BlockingQueue events = new ArrayBlockingQueue(65536);

Driver implementation : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-big-data-blog/blob/master/aws-blog-kinesis-producer-library/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/producer/demo/ClickEventsToKinesisTestDriver.java

But after that I am bit confused on how to integrate with executor service to call the necessary implementation of Kinesis client to put the record to the stream. Do I need to implement this using threads only ? Is there an alternate option.

Comment: I recommend you to check fluentd and use fluentd kinesis plugin to send logs to kinesis.